# I need help manipulating a text file using awk or sed (awk preferred)

Tags: bash, awk

I have two functions I need to program into a bash script on Ubuntu for my cs class but my teacher and his notes are unhelpful.

I have done most of the work on the project but I cannot figure out how to get a couple of things done. For reference the text file uses records of bills on each line in the format:

```
ID%Category%Detail%Amount%Year%Month%Day
```

where the % is the separator
an example being

```
3%Restaurant%Subway%6.25%16%3%13
```

two of the commands I can't figure out are

1) To sort through and display or add up the amounts (field 4) of all the records between two dates (year, month, day).

2) When generating a new record with user input, search through the txt file and set the ID(the first field) of the new record as the lowest missing record. So if I generate a new record and record 2 had been deleted prior set the new record's ID as 2. The way I am adding the new records to the text file is:

```
echo "$ID%$Category%$Detail%$amount%$year%$month%$day" file_name.txt
```

which the teacher gave as the example. Using this example I can add in everything just fine, but cannot figure out how to get it to generate the ID properly.

Thank you in advance and sorry for the lack of information. Like I said I would prefer if the answers use awk, but any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Do you pay this teacher?

Comment: You'll need to show us your work, and where specifically you are stuck.

Comment: It seems like you have 2 problems here. I'd recommend editting your Q down to focus on the first part for now. Add 2-3 records to the Q, and then show your expected output, plus your best attempt to solve that problem. (I find it hard to understand  the 2nd half of your Q, again, sample inputs, required output, current output, code and error msgs will help us help you). Good luck.

Comment: You need to specify your field separator and field number.  That's going to be `awk -F%` with `$4` and `sort -t% -n4`.  Just the sum: `awk -F% '{sum+=$4} END {print sum}' file_name.txt`.  Maybe you can figure out the rest?  That'd be the best way to learn this stuff.